# How to add custom button to sidebar?

Tags: admin-on-rest

In my case I'm using server-side session (not authClient with token in cookies/local storage). So instead of using default LogoutButton I want to place custom button which will do simple "POST /logout" action. There are some examples in docs how to place custom buttons on resource pages, but nothing about sidebar. Any advices/examples?

Answer (score 0):

A custom Sidebar is a custom Menu: 
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/AdminResource.html#menu ?

Comment: link to website is dead

Comment: Looks like it's up again